# Toggle stops working after dragging element to sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm writing a web application, that requires a drag and drop functionality.

The draggable object is pretty big, but it has a minimization button. However, after I drag the object to a sortable element, the minimization button stops working.

Here's the code sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/Alvyxaz/u7SdU/

Try clicking on the + sign before you drag the object to sortable, and after.

Any tips?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by using `.live` with a click event and `toggle()` instead of show/hide.

```
$('.minmax').live('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7SdU/8/

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! Got to look into this .live() method to figure out why it's working.